# Python How to prompt user to input a reference pointing to the first node of the linked list？

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

I'm working on a singly linked list problem. It is about writing a function to implement a recursive algorithm which counts the number of nodes in a singly linked list.

I'm stuck because I'm required to prompt users to input a reference pointing to the first node of the linked list.

But up to now I'm only able to write a program which users should input elements manually and finally count the node, not through a reference, and count the nodes of the linked list which the reference is pointing to.

Can anyone help me?

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node(None)

    def add(self, item):
        temp = Node(item)
        temp.next = self.head
        self.head = temp

    def countNodes(self, node):
        if not node: 
            return 0
        else:
            return 1 + self.countNodes(node.next)

    def getCount(self):
       return self.countNodes(self.head)


if __name__=='__main__':
    new = LinkedList()
    new.add(1)
    new.add(3)
    new.add(1)
    new.add(2)
    new.add(3)
    new.add(1)
    new.add(2)

    print ('Count of nodes is :',new.getCount())
```

To make it clearer, it is not necessary for the users to manually create a linked list like this. The user will input a variable, which is a reference pointing to the first node of a linked list, to my function.

Comment: forget about the code, first visualize and finalize what you want the user to be able to do with your program. then it will become much more clear to implement the logic.

Comment: Users can't input variables, they input strings. You need to come up with some sort of basic protocol how to interpret user input.